# BigQuery: Divided by sum of values in column to find the ratio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I have a simple table with two columns `Bin_name` (int) and `Count_in_this_bin` (int)

I want to convert it to the ratio of each bin to the total count in all bins.

I used the following query in Google BigQuery:

```
SELECT count_in_bin/(SELECT SUM(count_in_bin) FROM [table])
FROM [table]
```

Then I get

> error:Query Failed
>   Error: Subselect not allowed in SELECT clause

Can anyone let me now the correct way to do this kind of simple divide in BigQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  count_in_bin, 
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(count_in_bin) OVER() AS ratio
FROM [project:dataset.table]
```

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  count_in_bin, 
  count_in_bin / total AS ratio
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
(SELECT SUM(count_in_bin) total FROM `project.dataset.table`)
```

Comment: The standard sql method will still work if there is a join on the first table right ?

Comment: it should :o) if correctly construct. try and if issue - post new separate question and we will help

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for window/analytic functions.  In standard SQL this would be:

```
SELECT count_in_bin / SUM(count_in_bin) OVER () 
FROM [table]
```

In legacy SQL, you seem to need a subquery:

```
SELECT count_in_bin, count_in_bin / total_count_in_bin
FROM (SELECT count_in_bin, SUM(count_in_bin) OVER () as total_count_in_bin
      FROM [table]
     ) t
```

Comment: Hi I tried this, but it shows: Error: Missing function in Analytic Expression at: 1.50 - 1.57. Is this legacy sql syntax or standard?

Comment: I just tried again using StandardSQL dialect, it works, but it won't work in  legacy syntax.

Comment: @Noob. . . . How strange.  The `sum(count_in_bin) over ()` works in legacy SQL.  It is the division that throws off the expression.

Comment: Hi man, I was using the Legacy SQL, the query itself worked, but not when I include it in the division. Also, after I checked off the Legacy Syntax option in BigQueyr, I found the standard sql in bigquery actually support subquery. While to me the best solution is just to stick with the standard sql option in bigquery. Thanks

Comment: And yes the second version you provided worked, while the 1st one with SUM in division failed. BigQuery might expect the query to be more clear I guess?